# How to make the RHS integer numbers by multiplying both sides?

Tags: output-formatting

I have a list of identities as follows.

```
list = Table[With[{e = i^k}, HoldForm[Sum[e, {i, 1, n}]]], {k, 5}];
Column[# == Factor[ReleaseHold[#]] & /@ list] // TeXForm
```

> $$ \begin{array}{l}  \sum _{i=1}^n i=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1) \\  \sum
>  _{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\  \sum _{i=1}^n i^3=\frac{1}{4} n^2 (n+1)^2 \\  \sum _{i=1}^n i^4=\frac{1}{30} n (n+1)
>  (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right) \\  \sum _{i=1}^n i^5=\frac{1}{12}
>  n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right) \\ \end{array} $$

In order to allow the questions span across lines or pages, I have to remove the ratios by multiplying both sides with the smallest integers.

> $$ \begin{array}{l}  2\sum _{i=1}^n i= n (n+1) \\  6\sum _{i=1}^n i^2=
>  n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\  4\sum _{i=1}^n i^3= n^2 (n+1)^2 \\  30\sum
>  _{i=1}^n i^4= n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right) \\  12\sum _{i=1}^n i^5= n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right) \\ \end{array} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
list = Table[With[{e = i^k}, HoldForm[Sum[e, {i, 1, n}]]], {k, 5}];
RHSlist = Factor[ReleaseHold[#]] & /@ list;
factors = LCM @@ Denominator /@ Cases[#, Rational[_, _], All] & /@ RHSlist;
Column[# == Factor[ReleaseHold[#]] & /@ (factors list)] // TeXForm
```

> \begin{array}{l}
>  2 \sum _{i=1}^n i=n (n+1) \\
>  6 \sum _{i=1}^n i^2=n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\
>  4 \sum _{i=1}^n i^3=n^2 (n+1)^2 \\
>  30 \sum _{i=1}^n i^4=n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right) \\
>  12 \sum _{i=1}^n i^5=n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right) \\
> \end{array}